# Cloudfront AJAX 403 Forbidden

Tags: jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I just added Amazon cloudfront and my requests to certain jquery ajax addresses are starting to be forbidden.

If I check my console it says:

https://www.example.com/advertisers/interface/email/submit (403 forbidden)

But if I enter the same url in my browser:

https://www.example.com/advertisers/interface/email/submit (200)

What is going on? How can I fix this?

**Edit: More info from the console:**

```
jquery.js:8630 POST https://www.linkarus.com/advertisers/interface/email/submit 403 (Forbidden)
k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery.js:8630
n.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:8166
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:8311
(anonymous function) @ tasks.js:36
n.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4435
r.handle @ jquery.js:4121
```

Comment: Do you get any additional information with the 403 error? Is authentication required (either via a key, token, or credentials)?

Comment: Is your ajax sending a `POST` request? Entering the URL in your browser would send a `GET` request, which might explain why the two differ in the result.

Comment: Just added all the info from the console. Yes, it's a post request.

Comment: Have you set any restrictions for CloudFront in AWS?

Comment: @Justinas I have "Georestriction: disabled" but I think that is just default?

Comment: Ok solved it - I changed the origin protocol policy to say "match viewer"...

Comment: Hmmm oh dear now it seems to be blocking normal page access. Ah no maybe it is ok...